# Problema con aplicacion web

Tags: webservice, iis, timeout

Tengo una aplicacion web hecha en ASP.NET. Esta aplicacion funciona bien.

La forma en la cual esta aplicacion funciona es que a cada hora llama a un servicio web (tambien hecho en la misma aplciacion) para que sincronize cierto trabajo.

Lo que me doy cuenta que la automatizacion funciona bien durante 29 horas seguidas y luego pierde la conexion.

Se que esto es una configuracion de IIS pero a pesar que he cambiado el recycling varias veces, este sigle comportandose de la misma forma.

Como puedo hacer en que cuando tenga que reciclar vuelva a conectarse?

Si pongo el tiempo regular de intervalo de 1740 a 0, puede afectar la memoria del servidor?

Gracias,

Comment: Puedes comentarnos ¿Cómo haces iniciar dicho servicio? ¿Desde la app web en sí?¿Tienes un servicio de windows que lo inicia?¿Cómo lo monitoreas?

Comment: Hola, tengo una funcion que compare dateTime.now con la ultima vez que se ejecuto. Si la ultima que se ejecuto es igual a 1 hora, el servicio se ejecuta nuevamente
Este proceso es un API que he creado para poder automatizar el proceso sin tener que crear un servicio de Windows

Comment: una alternativa: podrías crear un servicio de windows que llame a esa función, cosa que dejas de depender del ciclo de reciclaje, eso sí, tendrías que revisar cómo mantienes la conexión de manera constante.

Comment: Si eso era el plan inicial pero el jefe de proyectos decidio no ir con un servicio web ya que si se necesitaban cambios, iba a tener que desistalarse y volverse a instalar y con el servicio web es solo cosa de compilar los cambios

Comment: Servicio Web != servicio de windows.

Comment: Si claro, por eso decia que no hicimos el servicio windows y decidimos crear un serivcio web en el cual cuando se llama periodicamente, este responde y nos da el resultado esperado.
El problema no es ese, es el que despues de 29 horas este pierde conexion y no se vuelve a conectar